# Logistic Regression: Strange Variable arises

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am using R to perform logistic regression on my data set. My data set has more than 50 variables.
I am running the following code:

```
glm(X...ResponseFlag ~ NetWorth + LOR + IntGrandChld + OccupInput, family = binomial, data = data)
```

When I see summary() I got the following output:

```
> summary(ResponseModel)

Call:
glm(formula = X...ResponseFlag ~ NetWorth + LOR + IntGrandChld + 
    OccupInput, family = binomial, data = data)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.2785  -0.9576  -0.8925   1.3736   1.9721  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   -0.971166   0.164439  -5.906 3.51e-09 ***
NetWorth       0.082168   0.019849   4.140 3.48e-05 ***
LOR           -0.019716   0.006494  -3.036   0.0024 ** 
IntGrandChld  -0.021544   0.085274  -0.253   0.8005    
OccupInput2    0.005796   0.138390   0.042   0.9666    
OccupInput3    0.471020   0.289642   1.626   0.1039    
OccupInput4   -0.031880   0.120636  -0.264   0.7916    
OccupInput5   -0.148898   0.129922  -1.146   0.2518    
OccupInput6   -0.481183   0.416277  -1.156   0.2477    
OccupInput7   -0.057485   0.218309  -0.263   0.7923    
OccupInput8    0.505676   0.123955   4.080 4.51e-05 ***
OccupInput9   -0.382375   0.821362  -0.466   0.6415    
OccupInputA  -12.903334 178.064831  -0.072   0.9422    
OccupInputB    0.581272   1.003193   0.579   0.5623    
OccupInputC   -0.034188   0.294507  -0.116   0.9076    
OccupInputD    0.224634   0.385959   0.582   0.5606    
OccupInputE   -1.292358   1.072864  -1.205   0.2284    
OccupInputF   14.132144 308.212341   0.046   0.9634    
OccupInputH    0.622677   1.006982   0.618   0.5363    
OccupInputU    0.087526   0.095740   0.914   0.3606    
OccupInputV   -1.010939   0.637746  -1.585   0.1129    
OccupInputW    0.262031   0.256238   1.023   0.3065    
OccupInputX    0.332209   0.428806   0.775   0.4385    
OccupInputY    0.059771   0.157135   0.380   0.7037    
OccupInputZ    0.638520   0.711979   0.897   0.3698    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 5885.1  on 4467  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 5809.6  on 4443  degrees of freedom
AIC: 5859.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 12
```

From the output, it is seen that some new variable like OccupInput2... has arisen. Actually OccupInput had values 1,2,3,...A,B,C,D.. But it did not happen for NetWorth,LOR.

I am new to R and do not have any explanation, why there are new variables.

Can anybody give me an explanation? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, `OccupInput` is a factor, and it has that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume that `OccupInput` in your model is a factor variable. R introduces so-called [dummy variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)), when you include factorial regressors in a linear model.

What you see as `OccupInput2` and so forth in the table are the coefficients associated with the individual factor levels (the reference level `OccupInput1` is covered by the intercept term).

You can verify the type of `OccupInput` from the output of the `sapply(data, class)` call, which yields the data types of the columns in your input data frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually I was trying to see the p-value of each variable. Can you please give me a suggestion, how can i handle this sitaution? or I should not include factor to the regression?

Comment: You are being given p-values in the `Pr(>|z|) ` column. However, they are somewhat (well actually extremely) suspect since some of your standard errors are the numerical equivalent of infinity on the log odds scale. You should be doing a better job of looking at your data before throwing it at an analytical tool.

Comment: I am sorry if I am fool, "You are being given p-values in the Pr(>|z|)", this is the p-value of different level of the factor, what if I want to get the p-value of the factor only?